# Polymer - Track app usage with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I'm trying to use Google Analytics (web) with my polymer app (updating the tracker object in routing.html as per [this GA SPA doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications)). I used the Polymer Starter Kit as a starting point. I'm not seeing any pageviews though, apart from `/` - what's the suggested way of tracking app usage?

**routing.html**

```
page('/topstories', function () {
  app.route = 'topstories';
  window.ga('set', 'page', '/topstories');
});

page('/about', function () {
  app.route = 'about';
  window.ga('set', 'page', '/about');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to setting the page value on the tracker, you also have to send the pageview hit to Google Analytics. In your route callback functions you'll need to add the line:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

You could also write a function that does all this for you, so you don't have to repeat the `set` and `send` calls every time.

```
function updatePage(path) {
  return function() {
    app.route = path.slice(1);
    ga('set', 'page', path);
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  }
}
```

The your page route declarations would look like this:

```
page('/topstories', updatePage('/topstories'));
page('/about', updatePage('/about'));
```

Comment: Interesting. I was working under the assumption that simply setting the value on the tracker would be enough but clearly the `send` in the main script is only executed on page load. Almost a schoolboy error on my part :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree it can be confusing at first. Check out this section on [How analytics.js works](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#how-analytics-js-works) to get a better big-picture view of the library.

Answer (score 1):

My solution takes advantage of the middleware-ish [page.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) handler:

```
// Routes
page('*', scrollToTop, closeDrawer, function(ctx, next) {
  ga('set', 'page', ctx.path); // simply add
  ga('send', 'pageview');      // these rows
  next();
});
```

But this also fires as the `/` route is initialised, so to not double count visits, remove the final `ga('send', 'pageview');` from your `<script>` block.